# How to use batch size to create a tensor within a custom TensorFlow Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tf.keras

I'm creating a custom TF layer and inside it I need to create a tensor of ones with something like this

```py
class MyLayer(Layer):
  def __init__(self, config, **kwargs):
    super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    ....

  def call(self, x):
    B, T, C = x.shape.as_list()
    ...
    ones = tf.ones((B, T, C))
    ...
    # output projection
    y = ...
    return y
```

Now the problem is the `B` (which is batch size) is None when the layer is evaluated, which is causing the `tf.ones` to fail with the following error:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-69-f3322a54c05c>:29 call  *
        ones = tf.ones((B, T, C))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper  **
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:3080 ones
        shape = ops.convert_to_tensor(shape, dtype=dtypes.int32)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py:163 wrapped
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1535 convert_to_tensor
        ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:356 _tensor_shape_tensor_conversion_function
        "Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: %s" % s)

    ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (None, 8, 128)
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: Try `ones = tf.ones(tf.shape(x).numpy())`. Also add a standalone code to better debug the issue if it doesn't work.

Comment: that looks interesting, will give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get a tensor with the same shape as `x` then you can use [tf.ones_like](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ones_like). Something like this:

```
class MyLayer(Layer):

  ....

  def call(self, x):
    ones = tf.ones_like(x)

    ...

    # output projection
    y = ...
    return y
```

which doesnt need to know the shape of `x` till runtime.

In general, however, we might need to know the shape of the input before runtime in which case we can implement the `build()` method in our layer which takes `input_shape` as a parameter and is called when we compile our model.

Example copied from docs [here](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/):

```
class Linear(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
        self.b = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units,), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
```